# How to dynamically output python dictionary to html in django?

Tags: python, html, django, dictionary, websocket

This is the data I get from socket dynamically and I would like to show it in a table like keys and values in html with django.

```
Received: 
{'power': 'ON', 'mode': 'AUTOMATIC', 'execution': 'ACTIVE', 'Xact': '235.70', 'Yact': '1468.86', 'Zact': '1.27', 'Xcom': '0.00', 'Ycom': '0.00', 'Zcom': '0.00', 'path_feedrate': '0.00', 'line': '1136849', 'Block': '1136849', 'program': '37262 S1 - .75 JET_imported_CNC.ORD\n'}
{'comms': 'NORMAL', '': '\n2018-08-08T17:11:51.0384', 'Sspeed': '60000.00\n'}
{'line': '1136860', 'Block': '1136860\n'}
{'Xact': '236.17', 'Xcom': '909.70', 'path_feedrate': '909.70\n'}
{'Xcom': '0.00', 'path_feedrate': '0.00', 'line': '1136872', 'Block': '1136872\n'}
{'line': '1136883', 'Block': '1136883\n'}
{'line': '1136895', 'Block': '1136895\n'}
{'line': '1136906', 'Block': '1136906\n'}
{'Xact': '236.52', 'Xcom': '677.44', 'path_feedrate': '677.44\n'}
{'Xcom': '0.00', 'path_feedrate': '0.00', 'line': '1136918', 'Block': '1136918\n'}
{'line': '1136929', 'Block': '1136929\n'}
{'line': '1136941', 'Block': '1136941\n'}
```

and more more output.....

I tried to use this, but it did not work.

```
{% block content %}
<table>
    {% for key, value in devDict.items() %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock content %}

{% block js %}
<script type="text/python3" src="{% static 'widgets/python/mtconnect.py'%}"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

And this is my python script, this is how i get the data:

```
import socket

HOST = "myHOST"
PORT = myPORT
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    buffer_size = 2048
    print("Received: ")
    while True:
        devData = s.recv(buffer_size).decode("utf-8").split("|")
        timeStamp = devData.pop(0)
        devDict = dict(zip(*([iter(devData)]*2)))
        print(devDict)
s.close()
```

Comment: what is the output for what you've tried?

Comment: there is no output when i try for loop with django. but when i just run my python code it gives me the output from above

Comment: `.items()` is correct. Not `.items`

Comment: .items() is not correct, because i am getting this error: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'devDict.items()'

Comment: Hmm how odd. Must be a thing with the templating engine then I guess. In a normal IDE that would work. I'm surprised it doesn't in django

Comment: can be reason that output is constantly being updated?

Comment: how do you pass `devDict` to the template? I'm also not convinced you've actually get a `dict` like object there... once you've done with it - what does `type(devDict)` show anyway?

Comment: I am passing it as devDict directly into for loop. type(devDict) does not show anything

Comment: If you are loading a webpage then whatever data is available should be printed into the table and then rendered statically and passed to the client. If the data changed inbetween times, the page would not change without extra code that handles the live changes.

Comment: Can you show the view or where exactly that you send the data to templates?

Comment: it is being send to f'widgets/{widget_name}/v{version}/index.html', in views.py.  Or am i importing it wrong? {% block js %}
<script type="text/python3" src="{% static 'widgets/python/mtconnect.py'%}"></script>
{% endblock js %}

Comment: too many comments, edit your post with relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that i faced was that there was no possible way to render data from socket to browser, since there are two different protocols. I had to build first a bridge between them, socket to websocket. I did this by using: https://github.com/yankov/webtcp . and then i was able to render data from socket to browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you receive a list of dictionaries and firstly you need to iterate over the list. Smthn like:

```
<table>
    {% for line in devDict %}
    <tr>
        {% for key, value in line.items %}
                <td>{{ key }}</td>
                <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```